# document.ready when jQuery's before the body tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>


        <script>
            $(function() {
                // $ is undefined
            });
        </script>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to wait for the document to load and load jQuery before executing the function?

Comment: Inverting the order of the two script tags isn't good enough?

Comment: You need to reference jquery before using jquery.

Comment: why don't you just load jquery first then do document ready. document ready is part of jquery, so it is impossible to use it without jquery

Comment: I know some people say to move scripts out of head and to the end of body, but the OP's post is overkill.

Comment: @Paul I've seen a lot of new standards putting it in the footer.

Comment: @AD7six I mean that if he had put his <Script src=jquery...></script> in HEAD like in the good old days, he wouldn't have to worry about trying to use $ before it was defined.

Comment: It's overkill because you don't need to wait for the document to be ready if your code is the last thing before the closing body tag.

Comment: @paul If he placed his scripts in the <head> exactly as it they are now, it would throw the same error. <head> vs end of body isn't the issue here.

Comment: @KevinB I'm assuming the jquery loading script goes in the head but the user script stays in the body, so that it is subsequent.  Obviously you can't use things before they are defined.

Comment: @Paul that negates the whole point of putting scripts at the end of the page. The only sort of js that should go in the head are things like [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

Comment: @AD7six My understanding of this might be flawed, but the concern is that loading JS blocks other activity and putting the JS last at least gives part of the page a chance to render so the user has something to look at while the JS loads instead of a blank screen. Perhaps that still matters for the few users still on dialup or other slow speed data, I would think for everyone else this is in the sub-second range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't feel like this is a good solution but if you really needed to you can load jQuery similar to how Google loads their JavaScript for their analytics service. You can write more code afterwards to detect when it has finished loading and execute a callback that contains what you want to do.

Rough demonstration taken and modified from this site http://www.tlswebsolutions.com/how-to-include-jquery-dynamically-aka-check-to-see-if-it-exists/

```
if(!(window.jQuery)) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('src', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js');
    s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## No

You're referencing `$` before it exists, that simply won't work.

Assuming `js/jquery.js` exists, this will work:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
        $(function() {
            // your code goes here
        });
</script>
```

Since the first script tag will define `$` before the second one refers to it.

### No need to wait for document ready

Hattip to @KevinB for pointing out this obvious additional point.

If script tags are in the head - the body doesn't exist when the script is loaded. For this reason it's common to use document ready to ensure that the html page exists before running javascript.

If script tags are at the foot of the page, the html already exists when the script is loaded and therefore there's no need to wait for a document ready event. As such the js code becomes:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
         // your code goes here
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to wait for the document to load and load jQuery before executing the function?

Comment: @WearetheWorld you can use a scriptloader but that doesn't seem necessary or in your interest here. It sounds like you've picked the wrong solution to a "bigger" problem - what is it you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Made simple for you -

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            // $ is undefined
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can.

```
function main() {
  if (! window.jQuery) {
    setTimeout(main, 100);
    return;
  }
  // Some code that uses jQuery
}

setTimeout(main, 100);
```

This also seems possible, but might not work as reliably with old browsers.

```
window.onload = function() {
  // Some code that uses jQuery
};
```